# Changing a variable inside a function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the visitor's OS, but it looks like I'm doing something wrong.

```
var OS = "N/A";

["windows", "linux", "mac"].forEach(function(item) {
    if(new RegExp(item).test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) {
        var OS = item;
    }
});

console.log(OS);
```

Any help, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the `var` inside the if condition, as you are redeclaring the variable. Only then, you can assign a new value to the variable on the outside.

```
var OS = "N/A";

["windows", "linux", "mac"].forEach(function Detect(item) {
    if(new RegExp(item).test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) {
        OS = item;
    }
});

console.log(OS);
```